# Cannot resolve module 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable'

Tags: material-ui

Just trying to migrate over to `"material-ui": "^1.0.0-alpha.11",` and have managed to fix most broken dependencies except the HOC `muiThemable`.

This seems to have been removed completely in the `next` branch. Is there still a way to retrieve the theme from the context in the same fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a new `withStyles` component inside the `styles` subdirectory that replaces